# "... it not be shown."

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, subjunctive-mood

I'm not new to English, but the phrase I've just read on cnn.com keeps bothering me:

*"CNN viewed the email on the condition that it not be shown."*

"It not be shown" - is this 100% grammatically correct? And if so, could somebody elaborate on its grammar roots and status?

If I were to construct a similar sentence I am sure I would use "... it won't be shown" (or: "it IS not shown" - but I like it less) - would that be incorrect/better/worse choice?

Comment: It is correct in that context.

Answer (score 15):

This  is a form of the subjunctive licensed by the preposition phrase *on (the) condition*. Many nouns, such as the noun *condition* can take content clauses using subjunctive constructions. Usually these clauses indicate the desired outcome of some implicit or explicit command or instruction.

Here are some more examples of the subjunctive following the noun *condition* from printed books. Notice that the verbs are in the plain form. They do not exhibit the third person 'S' that we would expect if these were examples of present simple verb forms:

- Calkins, a young Greek and philosophy instructor at Wellesley College, was given the opportunity to establish a laboratory on the condition that [she take time off and pursue advanced studies in psychology.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tfooCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA307&dq=%22on+the+condition+that+she+take%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVlNfF3pbSAhXBQI8KHY5KDLMQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20condition%20that%20she%20take%22&f=false)
- She was discharged by the Postal Service but later reinstated on the condition that [she take her medication](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Apfz8jk2EPwC&pg=PA216&dq=%22on+the+condition+that+she+take%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVlNfF3pbSAhXBQI8KHY5KDLMQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20condition%20that%20she%20take%22&f=false).
- She was granted permission — on the condition that [she take the exam apart from the male students](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tntEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA666&dq=%22on+the+condition+that+she+take%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVlNfF3pbSAhXBQI8KHY5KDLMQ6AEISDAI#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20condition%20that%20she%20take%22&f=false).

When head of the verb phrase in the content clause is the verb *BE*, the use of the subjunctive is more striking, of course, because the plain form of the verb *BE*, namely *be*, looks and sounds very different from the present simple forms *am, is* or *are*:

- A radio station eventually arranged to spend the night in the room, which Bruhns allowed only on the condition that [she be there to ensure security](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22on+the+condition+that+she+be+catious%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22on+the+condition+that+she+be+there%22).

**The Original Poster's example**

> - CNN viewed the email on the condition that [it not be shown].

Here we see a content clause using a subjunctive construction. The corresponding present simple version of the clause would be:

- it is not shown.

In the OP's (Original Poster's) example, we see the passive auxiliary *BE*, which heads the verb phrase, in the plain form. Because this is a subjunctive construction, the clause is negated by the word *not* occurring *before* instead of after this verb. It is a perfectly grammatically correct sentence.

Speakers of British English are less likely to use subjunctive constructions than American English speakers.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure I agree with that last statement. The OP's example [wouldn't sound strange](http://bbcradio3.tumblr.com/post/93513956423/when-edward-elgar-died-in-february-1934-he-left-a) on the BBC.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree it wouldn't sound strange at all! :) But for a lot of American English speakers subjunctive clauses are basically mandatory after certain verbs and nouns. For some American English speakers, if a subjunctive isn't used the sentence is ungrammatical. That's not the case for British English speakers like you and me, I don't think. For example the following would be completely grammatical for BE: "They recommend that she takes the Cambridge exam first". But for many AE speakers that's ungrammatical.

Answer (score -2):

The "it not be shown" part is not incorrect, but it does feel like something is missing from the end of phrase.

Not be shown to whom? Under what conditions?

Assuming that is the complete sentence, I personally have an issue with the sentence as a whole because it seems illogical to me, though not grammatically incorrect.

"it not be shown" implies that it is something you shall not do in the future, rather than in the past, else it should read "it has not been shown".

Bearing that in mind, how can CNN claim to have done something (viewed the e-mail, which occurred in the past) under the condition that you will not do something in the future?

Once the e-mail is viewed, should you break the condition and show it to someone else, it's not like they can "unview" it.

Here's an example of a phrase using "not be shown":

"He shall not be shown the light of day again."

Comment: *Not be shown to whom?* CNN is a broadcast network, *not be shown* means not aired on television. The whom is assumed to be the audience. *how can CNN claim to have done something under the condition that you will not do something in the future?* CNN claims to have done something under the condition that *it* will not do something in the future. They were allowed to see the email on the condition that they not broadcast an image of the email.

Comment: *Shall not be shown* is the future indicative passive. *that it not be shown* is subjunctive, common for complements to verbs of command or instruction.

Comment: Actually both the to whom and by whom are assumptions on your side. There's nothing implicitly stating that said showing should not be done by CNN to an audience (i.e., aired on TV). Without a context, I don't think my interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: @deadrat there may be a difference between the phrase the OP showed and the example in this answer using "not be shown", but the question was whether it's grammatically correct to use "[personal pronoun] not be shown". This answer states that it is grammatically correct to do so and provides an example.

Comment: @cogumel0 I give up. What is your interpretation?

Comment: @cogumel0 The OP states that it is grammatically correct ("it" being CNN's disclaimer). The OP is right. The OP poster states that it is illogical to him. If he says so. It's not illogical to a fluent speaker, though. The OP provides an example. Presumably, you're talking about his last sentence. That's example is not parallel to the statement under discussion.

Comment: In a sentence like this, whatever follows "on the condition that" is a promise that CNN made before viewing the email. Of course there is no way to be mathematically certain that they will never show the email to anyone else, even by accident. It is very rare that someone makes a promise whose fulfillment is a mathematically certainty. Whoever showed them the email took the risk that CNN will eventually violate the condition. -- In short, barring some unexpected contradiction in the context of the sentence, the sentence makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: This answer is entirely wrong. Please ignore it. The answerer doesn't seem to know much about the subjunctive construction in question.